# YouTube API thumbnail urls not resolving

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I am hoping this is a one off, but today I came across a video that reports the following when calling the "Videos: list" endpoint by a videoId:

```
"thumbnails": {
      "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/**uEGlS01**/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
      },
      "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/**uEGlS01**/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
      },
      "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/**uEGlS01**/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
      },
      "standard": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/**uEGlS01**/sddefault.jpg",
        "width": 640,
        "height": 480
      },
      "maxres": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/**uEGlS01**/maxresdefault.jpg",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 720
      }
    }
```

... but neither the "maxres" or "standard" urls render an image (they 404 and render the nasty YouTube default grey image).  Usually when those sizes were not available, those objects were not in the array.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

EDIT **

I should mention that the remainder of the thumb urls work as expected and embedding of the video fails to render a poster image with the exception of Chrome on desktop (which uses WEBP)

Comment: Maybe the video was deleted? That does seem odd.

Comment: @JacobH No the video exists but i will modify my question as i left out some critical info... the remainder of the thumb url's render as expected.

Comment: How about trying to clear cache?

Comment: It is not a caching issue... Tested that

Comment: I've also noticed sometimes YouTube does not render an image correctly. I always verify the image exists with a head request and check for 200 response.

Comment: ... the missing images have now shown up.  Looks like a hiccup at YouTube that I hope is an isolated incident.  Having to check every time for the existence of an image that YouTube reports to have via their API is a bit clunky hehe